# For loop is being ignored

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is the xyz loop getting ignored? Here is a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/B99CD/
Please keep in mind this is inside of a proprietary content management system I cant mention.
The fiddle does not run the function for some reason.  what happens is the tabs do not get set back to none and therefore all look active.  Any suggestions?

Edit the fieldsets exist.  I cant share that portion of the code. Sorry.

testing in ie10 and ff26.0

```
function tabAction(tab) {

    var numberOfTabs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var x = 0;
    var xyz = 0;
    //alert(tab);
    debugger;
    var loopEnd = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset").length;

    document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[tab].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[tab].style.clear = "both";
    document.getElementsByTagName("li")[tab].className = "active";

    if(tab > 5) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("li")[tab].className = "active"; // show task tab
        for(x = 6; x < loopEnd; x++) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[x].style.display = "block";
            document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[x].style.clear = "both";
        }
    }

    for(xyz = 0; xyz < numberOfTabs; xyz++){
        alert(xyz);
        if (xyz !== tab) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("li")[x].className = "none";
        }     
    }

    for(x = 0; x < loopEnd; x++)  {
        if (x !== tab) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[x].style.display = "none";
        }
        if (x > 5){
            document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[x].style.display = "none";// change this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work because you have `onLoad` selected in the sidebar, so your function is defined inside an anonymous `window.onload` function.

Comment: Your 'tabAction' function is not defined, check your fiddle settings.

Comment: Change it to one of the No Wrap choices. Another problem: there are no `fieldset` elements in the HTML, so all the `getElementsByTagName("fieldset")` calls return empty lists.

Comment: In your edit you're setting `numberOfTabs` to a `nodeList`. Shouldn't there be `.length` at the end?

Comment: @Barmar Post your .length comment as an answer and I will give you credit.  It helped out this question.

Comment: Why don't you accept TwighlightSun's answer, he noticed it before me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess numberOfTabs should be **document.getElementsByTagName("li").length**.

Besides the **numberOfTabs**, shouldn't the *x* in *document.getElementsByTagName("li")[**x**].className = "none";* be *xyz*.

And I don't think its a good idea to use **document.getElementsByTagName("li")** to get all the tabs, as you'll get error when there are other *<li>* tags in the HTML document. I suggest you wrap your tabs with an element and setting it's id, and you can use  **document.getElementById('xxxx').getElementsByTagName("li")**

Comment: Or give all the relevant tags a class, and use `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: +1 the problem is obviously the use of `x` instead of `xyz` inside the `xyz` loop. Unless that's another copying error he made here. I don't know how he expects us to tell us what's wrong with his code when he's changing it so many ways when he copies it.

Answer (score 3):

`numberOfTabs` is never set.

I can't derive from your code what the value should be. Looking at your HTML I would guess `7`.

Comment: I just added the number of tabs variable.  It was originally outside of the function

Answer (score 0):

I get an error at this line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[tab].style.display = "block";
```

There are no `fieldset` elements in your HTML, so `document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")[tab]` is undefined, and you can't set properties of `undefined`.

Comment: Edited question.  I cant share the fieldset part of the html.

Comment: If I can't get past that line of code, I can't debug your code for you. I guess you're on your own.